# The best way to pass objects between classes in different threads?

Tags: java

I have a Class "A" that is "runnable" and I make new objects out of Java unmarshallers. The MainGUI thread tries to access those instances by a get() that is already in the class "A". The instances that I created at class A, I made them static, so that they be available forever, but the problem when I get a new complete instance that has different properties, I have to compare the new instance with the previous's one data and keep the new one.

Is there a better way or design for that problem ?

How can I get the instances of Class "A" that are created at runtime without making them statics ?

Sample Code:

```
    public class SOAPMessagesFactory {

     private static GetCameraImageResponse                getCameraImageResponse;

// process here the msgs in another thread, not shown here in that snipped
     if (messageTag.equalsIgnoreCase("GetCameraImageResponse")) {
                try {
                    JAXBElement<GetCameraImageResponse> cameraImageResponse = unmarshaller.unmarshal(SoapBodyReader, GetCameraImageResponse.class);
                    getCameraImageResponse = cameraImageResponse.getValue();

                } catch (Throwable ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

public GetCameraImageResponse getCameraImageResponse() {

    if (getCameraImageResponse != null) {
        return getCameraImageResponse;
    } else {
        return null;
    }

}
     // in main gui

 public void UpdateGUI() {

        GetCameraImageResponse cameraImageResponse = messageFactory.getCameraImageResponse();

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `previous's one data and keep the new one` ? Are you replacing the instance ?

Comment: OP means that he want to keep state of last object(for comparision) and new one as well

Comment: can you provide code snippets?

Comment: I think my post answers your query.

Comment: Perhaps you need to look into the 'volatile' keyword

Comment: This code is mostly nonsense. The variable 'getCameraImageResponse' shouldn't be static, and it is very poorly named. You don't need to test a variable for null and return null if it's null: you only need to return the variable itself. You don't catch exceptions only to print a stack trace and keep going as though they haven't happened. Your updateGUI() method just creates a local variable. It has no external effect. It certainly doesn't update any GUI.

Comment: @EJP The updateGUI() is not a complete version, it is just an excerpt. Why it shouldn't be static ? how would you pass it to the Main GUI ?

Comment: I commented on the code you posted. I don't see the point of posting even that much of it if you don't want it commented on. Member variables should be static when and only when required. You haven't told us enough about the problem to justify it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a [Producer-Consumer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem) pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare a reference of type "A" in main and pass that to the other thread.
In the other thread perform the operations and assign the new instance of A to the reference.
Something like this

```
A aVariable;
Thread t = new Thread(new MyThread(aVariable));
t.start();
t.join();
populateGUI(aVariable);
```